# Android Change to a different strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, string, settings, system

I have a little problem I need to resolve. 
In my application I will have a settings where I will change the language of my app from english to swedish and back. So I wonder how I should do this? 

Can I change to a different strings.xml file or do I have to change all the text in my strings.xml manually when the user wants to change lanuage?


Please come with tips and examples how I should solve this!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change language programatically in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with this:

```
String languageToLoad  = "your language code";
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

With this you are basically just changing your locale, therefor also your language

Comment: So I make my own folder values-swe and then I put my strings.xml in swedish? But do I need all the other .xml files too? Like array, color, styles etc. ?

Comment: you have to create a values-swe folder and then you can put your strings.xml file in there. Just everything you want to be available in different languages

Comment: How do I then change to back to the default values folder?

Comment: The default folder is usually the folder with the english strings, so just redo this and set the locale to "en"

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the locale, locally:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
// Change locale settings in the app.
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale('fr');
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

[Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)